# Access a folder owned by another user from a windows machine using Samba

Tags: unix, groups

I have a Centos VM with Samba server and a user on that machine called smbuser in group smbuser. I can connect to my samba share /home/smbuser from my Windows 7 PC no problem. Also on the Centos VM I have another folder /home/ftpuser owned by ftpuser:ftpuser. I set up another samba share to allow smbuser access to this folder but when I try to connect to it from the Windows machine I get an access denied error. So I changed ownership of the ftpuser folder so it was owned by smbuser and it works.

The problem is now that I can't connect to ftpuser with my ftp client. I need both means of access - smb for working on files and ftp for transferring large quantities of data as fast as possible. (Samba is slow). I tried putting the smbuser into the ftpuser group but that didn't work. Please could someone enlighten me - I'm new to the concept of unix groups and exactly how they work.

Comment: You need to setup an ACL for the folder so both users have access (this is the "best" way to do it). I don't know linux well enough to tell you the exact syntax, but it should be in `man setfacl` or `man setacl`.

Comment: Thanks. I can get this to work on a normal directory in my main partition but when I try it in the actual directory I need it to work with (which is mounted as an LVM volume inside the ftpuser's home folder) it doesn't work - premission denied. I double checked the ACL but can't find anything wrong. Here it is:
[root@CENTOS-OPENBD home]# getfacl ftpuser/
# file: ftpuser
# owner: ftpuser
# group: ftpuser
user::rwx
group::---
other::---
default:user::rwx
default:user:smbuser:rwx
default:group::---
default:mask::rwx
default:other::---

Answer (score 1):

http://www.unixref.com/guides/chmodGuide.html

they also have a nice automatic calculator at the bottom!

Answer (score 0):

Try adding:

```
valid users = @commongroup
force group = commongroup
create mask = 0775
directory mask = 0775
```

To your share in your smb.conf file where "commongroup" is a group name both belong to.
For the above to work both users should be in a common group, and you might need to chown the folders that already exist to be owned by this common group.

If you use the "ftpuser" group above and want to add "smbuser" you can do:
`usermod smbuser -g ftpuser`

Comment: Hi. Thanks. I tried this but it didn't work either. I'm still getting a permission denied error when trying to connect from windows. Is it something to do with the fact that the directory I'm trying to access is a mounted partition?